# Deploy and run Laravel 5.2 on Live Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

Hi I am deploying my project laravel 5.2 on windows server 5.2 I use public I.P and make portward in router. My concern is how to run my laravel project without using php artisan serve ? . I already tried to use virtualhost but it works only if I am in the same network.

Thank you in advance.